# How to return a PageReference to create a sObject in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I know how to return a PageReference to edit and view a sObject:

```
PageReference ref =  new ApexPages.StandardController(bnk).edit();
```

But the StandardController class hasn't any method like create.

How can I return the page to create the sObject.

I alse know the methed like:

```
PageReference ref =  new PageReference('/a00/e');
```

but the sObject has many lookup fields.This method can't take out the reference lookup fields.It only can create a standalone sObject.

So how to return the create page and also take out the reference lookup fields?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem when trying to add a [Save and New](http://www.fishofprey.com/2012/03/salesforce-save-and-new-method-for.html) button. It seems odd that the StandardController doesn't have a new() method that returns a PageReference.

If your Apex class is going to be deployed to another Salesforce org (E.g. added to an outbound change set, put in a managed or unmanaged package, or deployed using Eclipse) I'd avoid hard coding the custom objects key prefix as this could change between orgs. Instead, use the DescribeSObjectResult to get the KeyPrefix.

```
public PageReference customObjectPageReference() {
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = YourCustomObject__c.SObjectType.getDescribe();
    // Add /o to end of URL to view recent
    return new PageReference('/' + R.getKeyPrefix() + '/e');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you're asking how to set the lookup fields in my answer below. If, however, you're asking how to remove the lookup fields, you would need to edit the PageLayout, but that would also remove the fields from the Edit page. If you need the fields on the Edit page, but not on the Create Page, you would need to create a new Create Visualforce page for your object and set the redirect to that page.

---

The create page is the edit page without an `id` parameter. The code you have should work:

```
PageReference ref =  new PageReference('/a00/e');
```

To change any parameters sent to the new Page through the `PageReference`, use the `getParameters()` method. The example below puts in a parameter for the Account Lookup (`CF00NC0000004htI5` is the Field Id in my Development Edition).

```
PageReference.getParameters().put('CF00NC0000004htI5', 'sForce');
```

The Field Id can be found by going to Setup > Create > Objects > [Your Object] > [Your Field]. Once there, look for the Field Id in the page address (URL) following the `/` (but before the `?` if there is a `?`). For example, my field URL is: `https://instance.salesforce.com/00NC0000004htI5?setupid=CustomObjects`. Once you have the Id, add `CF` before it.

For lookup fields, you may want to set the `CF`+FieldId+`_lktp` parameter as well. That sets the Id of the referenced record.

Here's the full method I'm using to get the next page.

```
public PageReference NextPage()
{
    Account a = [Select Id, Name From Account Where Name like '%sForce%' Limit 1];

    PageReference myPage = new PageReference('/a03/e');

    // set the ID on a lookup field
    myPage.getParameters().put('CF00NC0000004htI5_lktp', a.Id); 
    // set the Name on a lookup field
    myPage.getParameters().put('CF00NC0000004htI5', a.Name);

    myPage.setRedirect(true);
    return myPage;
}
```

Comment: Too much trouble,but I can only achieve it by this way. Why salesforce don't provider some easy method.

Comment: One more question.When I published my object to production environment from develop environment,will it(the id) change?  +Matthew Keefe

Comment: Possibly. If you created the field in production before refreshing your sandbox, the IDs would be the same. If you created the field in your sandbox, the IDs would be different.